# threads error in running stanford LLDA tmt scala models

Tags: scala, models

when I run stanford LLDA tmt scala models, I encounter a few problems. One of them is a thread error when I try to do inference with LLDA tmt model. The code I am running is exactly the one provided by Shreyas Karnik in the sourceforge link,

@Skarab: Here are the links to the code which I used to bit.ly/ocK2T9 (learning) and bit.ly/qIWb6C (inference) please let me know if you still encounter any errors.

The error message is,

---

Command started: Fri Jun 21 21:34:48 CDT 2013
java -Dscalanlp.distributed.hub=socket://crick7.mayo.edu:41080/hub -Dscalanlp.distributed.id=/tmt/0 -Xmx100000m edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.TMTMain "/data4/bsi/nlp/s110067.sharp/bioask/tmtModels/example-7-llda-infer.scala"

Loading model ...

```
TSVFile("test.csv") ~> IDColumn(1) ~> Column(2) ~> TokenizeWith(SimpleEnglishTokenizer.V1() ~> CaseFolder() ~> WordsAndNumbersOnlyFilter() ~> MinimumLengthFilter(3))
```

Generating output ...
[Concurrent] 128 permits
[Concurrent] 128 permits

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:45)
    at scalanlp.stage.Column.map(ColumnSelectors.scala:51)
    at scalanlp.stage.Column.map(ColumnSelectors.scala:46)
    at scalanlp.stage.generic.Mapper$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Mapper.scala:36)
    at scalanlp.stage.Item.map(Item.scala:32)
    at scalanlp.stage.generic.Mapper$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Mapper.scala:36)
    at scalanlp.stage.generic.Mapper$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Mapper.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.next(Iterator.scala:335)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.next(Iterator.scala:335)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.data.concurrent.Concurrent$$anonfun$map$2.apply(Concurrent.scala:96)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.data.concurrent.Concurrent$$anonfun$map$2.apply(Concurrent.scala:88)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tmt.data.concurrent.Concurrent$$anon$4.run(Concurrent.scala:45)
```

Would you give help? highly appreciate it!

Comment: To replicate prob, you shd state: scala release, JVM release, operating system, your memory and processor, other relevant

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue of tmt-0.4.0 for many users. tmt-0.2.1 works just fine.
But the support for tmt-0.4.0 has been discontinued and for tmt-0.2.1 even before that. 
You can check out http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/, which also has easy to start GUIs available such as http://www.themacroscope.org/?page_id=391.

Answer (score 0):

Check any .csv files for DOS/Unix incompatibility.

My experience may be relevant: 
I was also getting the error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException, when running tmt-0.4.0 from a command line on Windows. My workflow had a python program splitting my data set into training and test .csv files.   But they were written in DOS mode.  See for example, 
http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html

A confirmation of this is that when opening them in Excel, there was an extra line, and when opening them in Emacs, there's a telltale ^M.

I ran dos2unix on the .csv files, and then the TMT Scala programs worked.